# How to handle Cancel button from 'Share Location' using python-telegram-bot

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a button asking the user to 'Share his location'.

I'm having a problem when the user press the Cancel button.

How can I intercept/handle the Cancel button.

Best Regards.
Kleyson Rios

Comment: What is the *problem* you're having? We can't help you if we don't know the problem.

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani When the user press cancel I need to capture the 'cancel command' to show the user a message with new buttons.